# ¿Cómo organizar una app Express con muchas rutas?

Tags: nodejs, express

Estoy haciendo una app con *NodeJS* y *Express*. El problema es que la aplicación empieza a crecer y el código se hace ilegible. Quiero algún consejo de organizar las rutas, o alguna manera eficiente que me sugieran usar.

La app la manejo con los archivos clásicos **app.js** y la carpeta **routes** de la siguiente manera:

**app.js**

```
var indexRouter = require('./routes/index');
var usersRouter = require('./routes/users');
var groupsRouter = require('./routes/groups');
var calendarRouter= require('./routes/calendar');
//more code
app.use('/', indexRouter);
app.use('/users', usersRouter);
app.use('/groups', groupsRouter);
app.use('/calendar',calendarRouter);
```

**routes**

```
├ users.js
├ groups.js
├ calendar.js
└ database
  ├ dbUsers.js
  └ dbGroups.js
```

De esta manera funciona muy bien, cada módulo se encarga de lo que le corresponde y lo referente a la base de datos también tiene sus propios módulos (que cuando empiezan a crecer también se complica). Luego dentro de cada uno hay distintas rutas para cada acción.

Por ejemplo:

```
/users/create
/users/edit
/users/photos

/groups/members
/groups/parties
/groups/photos
//more routes
```

Hasta aquí es manejable pero cuando cada una de ellas empieza a crecer se complica mantenerlo. Por ejemplo `/groups/parties` tendrá las rutas `/create`, `/edit`, `/photos` y otras más. Desarrollar toda la lógica de cada ruta principal en el mismo archivo lo hace extenso e ilegible.

¿Cómo debería organizar los módulos cuando las rutas empiezan a crecer mucho?